# Call php file into html on button clicked and replace existing content

Tags: php, html, import

Hello I am trying to handle Nav bar where are 4 buttons and on click I would like to include another php file into same one.

My nav bar look like this:

```
<body>

    <div id="dock-container">
        <div id="dock">
        <ul>


            <li><span>Sony Ericsson</span><?php include ('menu.php') ?>"<img src="3.png"/></a></li>
      <li><span>test</span><a href="http://sonyericsson.com"><img src="4.jpg"/></a></li>
       <li><span>test</span><a href="http://sonyericsson.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
        <li><span>test</span><a href="http://sonyericsson.com"><img src="2.jpg"/></a></li>


        </ul>
        <div class="base"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and file which should be include is

```
<?php

echo "Ahoj";

?>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778928/javascript-include-file-at-onclick

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you need to make an `AJAX request`. There are plenty of ways to do this but using `jQuery ajax()` Method would be the easiest. You can implement something like this.

```
$("#click_button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_FILE", success: function(result){
        $("#fourth_button").html(result);
    }});
});
```

PS: replace `URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_FILE` with the actual `URL` of your actual file for e.g `http://example.com/includes/file.php`

Thanks